# how to api token extraction using Regular Expression Extractor in Sampler Header

Tags: jmeter

I receive using  View result Tree
 Result Tab

```
 POST data: auth-token=%24%7BBEARER%7D&mobileNumber=919106606909
```

This is new for me  I tried  some of reguler expression such as auth-token:(.*) ,auth-token:(.+?)

Actual Result

```
POST https://api.test.parkitup.com.au/api/v1/changeMobileNumber

POST data:
auth-token=%24%7BBEARER%7D&mobileNumber=919106606909

[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 52


Expected 

auth=token= eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJwYXJraXR1cC11c2VyLXV1aWQiOiI2NjZiNjViMy02YTA2LTRmOGQtYWNkMi0yZDM2ZTcxNmExYTMiLCJwYXJraXR1cC11c2VyIjp7InVzZXJJZCI6MywidXNlclV1aWQiOiI2NjZiNjViMy02YTA2LTRmOGQtYWNkMi0yZDM2ZTcxNmExYTMiLCJtb2JpbGVOdW1iZXIiOiI5MTk4NzkwODI4MzgiLCJvdHBIaXN0b3J5IjpbXX0sInBhcmtpdHVwLXVzZXItaWQiOjMsImV4cCI6MTU1ODY5NzgxMzQ2N30.tjZ_zJaaMArzT_MPr6oCpazh-q2gfztLRP10Pz5CE3A
```

[image: Response of Token]

[image: Regular Expression Extractor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [ASCII Encoding Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp), if we look into the `auth-token=%24%7BBEARER%7D` into the post data we will find that,

- Character "**$**" is encoded as "**%24**"
- Character "**{**" is encoded as "**%7B**"
- Character "**}**" is encoded as "**%7D**"

So from your post data it is clear that you are sending parameters with the request with encoding enabled. But the variable is not defined anywhere previously.
Variable "BEARER" has to be defined at Regex extractor.

If you have used Regular Expression Extractor then set the "`Reference Name`" as "`BEARER`" as you have used `${BEARER}` as variable in the request.

Comment: I have added the variable BEARER at regular Expression Reference Name will  provide you the screen shot. currently it is not fetching the variable.

Comment: Could you please share the response from where you are trying to extract the auth token?

Comment: Under Sampler Request tab  update u the question also                                                                        auth-token:  eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJwYXJraXR1cC11c2VyLXV1aWQiOiI2NjZiNjViMy02YTA2LTRmOGQtYWNkMi0yZDM2ZTcxNmExYTMiLCJwYXJraXR1cC11c2VyIjp7InVzZXJJZCI6MywidXNlclV1aWQiOiI2NjZiNjViMy02YTA2LTRmOGQtYWNkMi0yZDM2ZTcxNmExYTMiLCJtb2JpbGVOdW1iZXIiOiI5MTk4NzkwODI4MzgiLCJvdHBIaXN0b3J5IjpbXX0sInBhcmtpdHVwLXVzZXItaWQiOjMsImV4cCI6MTU1ODc3MjYwMTgyNH0.laOSKepPcW-bcNUOH6QnD9cNUk88HBnpuLUe46F47ZU

Comment: In regular Expression Extractor setting change "Field to check" to "Response Header".

Comment: thanks updated but respose is like this it takes empty  token. here I have provided Parmater as   ** auth-token ${BEARER) **